# Check if a string contains another string twice

Tags: java, string, list

I have a for loop which iterates through a maplist and now I want to check every entry of the maplist if it contains a certain String more than once and then delete all Strings except the first one which occurs but I have no clue how to do it.

```java
for (Map<String, String> entry : mapList) {
    String line = "";
    for (String key : entry.keySet()) {
        if (StringUtils.containsAny(key, "5799"){
            line += entry.get(key) + "|";
        }
        list1.add(line);
    }
}
```

I am thankful for every idea.

Comment: Exactly twice or at least twice?

Comment: good question: at least twice

Comment: Well, you could use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to find all matches of the string and replace all but the first with the empty string `""`.

Comment: Another question: would it be a _certain_ string only or any repeated string? Your question seems to indicate you could have input like `"a|b|c|a|d|c"` - would you want to remove the second `a` only or the second `c` as well? To make it easier to understand your requirements, could you provide some examples?

Comment: I would want to remove any duplicates so the second c as well

Comment: Well, in that case (and that still is a guess because I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements): split the string, put the elements into a `LinkedHashSet` end rebuild the string from that. The order of elements would be preserved and any duplicates would be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if `key` contains a string `s` at least twice, and to remove the second occurrence, use `indexOf` twice, with the second call starting the search after the first occurrence:

```
static String removeSecond(String key, String s) {
    int idxFirst = key.indexOf(s);
    if (idxFirst != -1) {
        int idxSecond = key.indexOf(s, idxFirst + s.length());
        if (idxSecond != -1) {
            return key.substring(0, idxSecond) +
                   key.substring(idxSecond + s.length());
        }
    }
    return key; // Nothing to remove
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(removeSecond("mississippi", "ss")); // prints: missiippi
System.out.println(removeSecond("mississippi", "i"));  // prints: missssippi
System.out.println(removeSecond("mississippi", "pp")); // prints: mississippi
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to remove all duplicates, i.e. leave only the first occurrence, keep searching. For best performance of building the new string, use `StringBuilder`.

```
static String removeDuplicates(String key, String s) {
    int idx = key.indexOf(s);
    if (idx == -1)
        return key; // Nothing to remove
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    int prev = 0;
    for (int start = idx + s.length(); (idx = key.indexOf(s, start)) != -1; prev = start = idx + s.length())
        buf.append(key.substring(prev, idx));
    return (prev == 0 ? key : buf.append(key.substring(prev)).toString());
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(removeDuplicates("mississippi", "ss")); // prints: missiippi
System.out.println(removeDuplicates("mississippi", "i"));  // prints: misssspp
System.out.println(removeDuplicates("mississippi", "s"));  // prints: misiippi
System.out.println(removeDuplicates("mississippi", "ab")); // prints: mississippi
```

Answer (score 3):

From your comments I assume your requirements are as follows:

- You have string that contains multiple parts delimited by the pipe character `|`, e.g. `"a|e|b|c|a|c|a|d"`
- You want to remove all repeating strings while preserving the order of elements, e.g. you want `"a|e|b|c|d"`

To achieve that you could split your string at the pipe, collect the elements into a `LinkedHashSet` and rejoin the elements using the pipe.

Example using Java 8:

```
//The pipe needs to be escaped because split() interprets the input as a regex
Set<String> elements = new LinkedHashSet<>( Arrays.asList( input.split( "\\|" ) ) );
//rejoin using the pipe
String output = elements.stream().collect( Collectors.joining( "|" ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all occurrences except the first one:

```
public static String removeExceptFirst(String master, String child) throws Exception {
    int firstIndex = master.indexOf(child);
    int lastIndexOf = master.lastIndexOf(child);
    if (firstIndex == lastIndexOf) {
        if (firstIndex == -1) {
            throw new Exception("No occurrence!");
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Only one occurrence!");
        }
    }

    while (true) {
        firstIndex = master.indexOf(child);
        lastIndexOf = master.lastIndexOf(child);
        if (firstIndex == lastIndexOf) {
            return master;
        }
        master = master.substring(0, lastIndexOf) + master.substring(child.length() + lastIndexOf);
    }
}
```